# how to use distinct to use join two table in mysql

Tags: mysql, distinct

This is my sql query to show hotels with price below 500

```
select a.*, b.room_price, b.hotel_id  
from hotels a , hotel_room_type b 
where a.sub_destination_id=1 
and a.destination_id=1 and 
a.id = b.hotel_id 
and b.room_price BETWEEN 0 AND 500
```

here showing duplicate record
ids 190 have come two time , how can i solve
[image]

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` just like you said in the title.

Comment: You should save your image as png to save the quality

Comment: Use this    select distinct a.*, b.room_price, b.hotel_id  
from hotels a , hotel_room_type b 
where a.sub_destination_id=1 
and a.destination_id=1 and 
a.id = b.hotel_id 
and b.room_price BETWEEN 0 AND 500

Comment: You'll get a row per room. If one hotel has more that one type of room (usually the case) you'll get duplicate rows. It's just what you're asking to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to remove redundant data. You can achieve this by using [group by](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) clause.

```
SQL> SELECT a.*, b.room_price, b.hotel_id FROM hotels a INNER JOIN  hotel_room_type b ON a.id =b.hotel_id where a.sub_destination_id=1 AND a.destination_id=1 AND b.room_price BETWEEN 0 AND 500 GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
SELECT a.*, 
   b.room_price, 
   b.hotel_id 
FROM   hotels a 
   INNER JOIN hotel_room_type b 
           ON a.id = b.hotel_id 
WHERE  a.sub_destination_id = 1 
   AND a.destination_id = 1 
   AND b.room_price BETWEEN 0 AND 500 
GROUP  BY a.id
```